# Receiving web cam streaming to Android

Tags: android, sockets

I'm working on an Android Application which can receive web cam streaming.
What I wrote is shown below.

1. Make a new socket (TCP)
2. Make BufferedInputStream (getting input stream from socket)
3. Read BufferedInputStream and check it's valid header that I made or not.
4. If it's valid header, move on to 5. If it's not go back to 3.
5. Run the loop which is read data size (which is from header that server sent) amount of bytes from BufferedInputStream.
6. Convert byte into Bitmap and draw on ImageView.
7. Go back to 3.

I didn't compress the frame from the server, size of each frame is 640*480.
My application is spending so much time on step 5.
Would you recommend me a different method to receive web cam streaming or frames with less delay?
What would be your best method?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my 2 cents:
1- sending uncompressed video doesn't seem like a great idea, unless you have a very limited computational power and good amount of network bandwidth. maybe your webcam can compress the video already by itself

2- unless you want to implement this for fun, don't reinvent the wheel, use [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), it can handle many type of media streaming and it's very performant.
3- Playing a video in an ImageView is not a good idea anyway, if you really want to do it yourself use a [TextureView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/TextureView.html)

Comment: Thank you for your tips.
I'm trying to make streaming in real time as possible.
I think I should check compressing time and try TextureView as you said.